# Retain line breaking behaviour inside macro

Tags: math-mode, macros, line-breaking

I use a macro which just wraps its argument in a pair of delimiters (brackets). It interferes with the way LaTeX would normally wrap an inline math expression. The following illustrates:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\collapse}[1]{\{{#1}\}}
\newcommand{\apply}[2]{#1[#2]}

\begin{document}
Here's a regular paragraph to indicate the point at which text would
normally wrap.

word word word word word word word word word word word word $\collapse{\apply{(T + T')}{D + D'}} > C$,
\end{document}
```

I don't want the {(T + T )[D + D ]} > C to run off the edge of the page but rather to wrap onto the next line. If I inline the 'collapse' macro, then indeed it wraps as one would expect.

Is this easy to achieve whilst still retaining my 'collapse' macro? I have tried /allowbreak, but with no success.

This is probably relevant: [Line break in macro](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/124195/line-break-in-macro)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the grouping in your definition of `\collapse`.  `{...}` is not neutral in math mode, it says the enclosed expression must not be broken over lines.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\collapse}[1]{\{ #1 \}}
\newcommand{\apply}[2]{#1[#2]}

\begin{document}
Here's a regular paragraph to indicate the point at which text would
normally wrap.

word word word word word word word word word word word word $\collapse{\apply{(T + T')}{D + D'}} > C$,
\end{document}
```